# ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80131509 "(null)"

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, msbi, foreach-loop-container

[SSIS ForEachLoop Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3066Q.png)

I am trying to load multiple excel files with multiple sheets but after deploy into server only i am getting this error.

The `GetEnumerator` method of the `ForEach Enumerator` has failed with error `0x80131509 "(null)"`. This occurs when the `ForEach Enumerator` cannot enumerate.

i also changed in the properties `Run64BitRuntime = false`. anyone can suggest me what to do for this error?

[FOReach loop container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Xt7.png)

Comment: When you say you are getting error only after deployment, is it working locally? Can you post sample data belonging to say two sheets in a single excel file to better understand? Also, screenshot of the ForEachLoop container and what is being set will help.

Comment: yes it is working locally and also in that server where i will deploy. but after deploy only i am getting this error message.

Answer (score 1):

This error gets thrown when trying to enumerate NULL.
It looks like, once deployed, your SSIS package is not finding any excel files, and returning NULL, instead of an empty list.

Sources;

- [Foreach loop container in SSIS using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174813/foreach-loop-container-in-ssis-using-variable)
- [ssis error : foreach in foreach loop container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328986/ssis-error-foreach-in-foreach-loop-container)

I'd suggest to put some logging in your package Before the enumeration to see if anything is found, then redeploy it, run and check your logs.